# Question 1553415 and 1553653 re-open request

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, reopen-request

Not focused: [What explains this poor intercontinental internet bandwidth? (Asia to Europe)](https://superuser.com/questions/1553415/what-explains-this-poor-intercontinental-internet-bandwidth-asia-to-europe)

Marked as duplicate: [Why is this international internet traffic routed so inefficiently?](https://superuser.com/questions/1553653/why-is-this-international-internet-traffic-routed-so-inefficiently)

---

I had a question. As you may know, it's a challenge to ask the right question or look for answers if you don't have any knowledge on the topic.

Thus I not only asked a question about the problem I was experiencing, but also asked for clarification on a peculiarity I found while investigating that problem - for my comprehension of the mechanics unrelated to the question. However, because of this, the original question was marked as not focused. This action, I completely agree with.

I fixed it, by moving the peculiarity to a new question, and editing the original one to be only about the initial problem. While on the same topic, the questions are unrelated.

Now the new question got marked as a duplicate. The edited question is still closed as not focused. Does that seem right to you?

Comment: I've  reopened the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why our moderator @davidpostill reopened this.

Neither question was a good fit for this site. No one, unless they work for your ISP is going to know why they choose to route this way. (other than contracts or design) It's why the ISP on network diagrams is a cloud. No one knows how the ISP inter-switched network operates from A <---> B, it's company specific & private. It may change packet to packet based off of the individual routers decisions from interface/link load ect. Even if someone here did or does work for them, discussing the inter-switched carrier grade networks of ISP's would be off-topic per our help section guidelines. ~(personal & home networking).

"While on the same topic, the questions are unrelated.

Now the new question got marked as a duplicate. The edited question is still closed as not focused. Does that seem right to you?"

~ Yes, either you are disingenuous with your petition, or you really didn't understand what I was trying to tell you in the comments.
The two questions were most certainly related.

I really doubt anyone is going to attempt to answer it, if they do it will be a generic meaningless answer that will have nothing to do with your ISP,  not help you solve anything, and will not help future readers.

For these reasons, I am petitioning the rest of the community moderators to vote and close this question. [Why is this international internet traffic routed so inefficiently?](https://superuser.com/questions/1553653/why-is-this-international-internet-traffic-routed-so-inefficiently)

You can also refer to this post if you question my voting decisions. 
[Do we need better definitions for off-topic questions in the help center?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13601/do-we-need-better-definitions-for-off-topic-questions-in-the-help-center)

Comment: The first question's answer would explain that PLDT likely has bad contracts with the backbone ISP's in Hong Kong - any server outside of the Philippines that goes through Hong Kong turns out to have a capped bandwidth of 200-300 KB/s, regardless of physical distance. When depending on an intercontinental internet connection, it is important to be aware of such limitations - and take this into account when choosing an internet provider. The question - although perhaps not the answer - is definitely related to "personal and home computer networking", and thus on-topic for superuser.

Comment: It appears the second question is off-topic to superuser, as it is not about "personal and home computer networking". It is important to note, that you are wrong though, because these two questions are most certainly related indeed, but still fundamentally different, requiring different answers. The second question's answer involves explaining a limitation of the BGP, that it does not prevent choosing a route that is inefficient. Also, Cogent replied to my inquiry, saying that their connectivity with Asia is simply poor, and they are working on improving it. So it is **not** a duplicate.

Comment: -_- unfortunately it seems **you still don't get it**. So I'm not going to waste anymore time on it. Good luck with your question. I will remove my comments from it. I would suggest you do the same if you would like someone to try and explain it to you. For whatever reason people avoid messy comment sections.

Comment: Don't worry about it, and thank you. I have answered my own question, perhaps it may clear things up - and I do believe it will be of use to future readers with similar issues, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered to answer my own question. With regard to off-topicness, I did find lot of other questions about BGP on this website - that were not closed as off-topic either. But feel free to migrate it to another StackExchange site, where possible and/or appropriate.