# Incorrect migration of post (to Android Enthusiasts)

Tags: support

I have a question about my Super User post: [Issues in communicating via IPSec (StrongSwan) between an Android client and its gateway (IKEv2)](https://superuser.com/questions/1639744/issues-in-communicating-via-ipsec-strongswan-between-an-android-client-and-its)

The day I had posted my question, the moderator David Postill had decided that it was off-topic, closing it in SuperUser and migrating it to Android Enthusiasts. Please, understand that this question relates to the **server-side configuration**, I **cannot** edit the ciphers used on the client-side. In the question you can clearly see (and I believe I pointed out too) that everything is working fine, up until to the `received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify, no CHILD_SA built`. As I point out there, this is due to (to my knowledge) either a mismatch in ciphers or an invalid `ts` config. Both of these parameters **cannot** be controlled on the client-side, only on the server.

Please, I ask of the moderator in question to review this issue once more, this time being more careful and not as superficial as before as to not confuse this with a question about configuration of the client.

Comment: The configuration right under the explanation section contains the configuration, where there is the `proposals` section which has all the supported ciphers from the server. I also specify that those ciphers were taken directly from the strongSwan wiki and I even link to from where I got them.

Comment: I've "unmigrated" it.

Comment: @ramhound Mods can clear the migration history on our side which brings it back.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, your question **was not closed**, it was migrated.

I agree that your post shouldn't have been migrated, but keep in mind our moderators are volunteers, and just like the rest of us **are human**.

It's not unusual for no comment to be left by our moderators when a question is closed or migrated.
(I personally think this could use some improvement.)

They give out very bad advice from time to time, and every once and a while close a question that IMHO shouldn't be closed, & Sometimes reopening questions I thought should have remained closed. Given the volume of questions asked on this site per day, it surprises me that our current moderators do as well of a job as they do to be perfectly honest with you. Our community members are also given authority to review and vote to close after a certain amount of rep is recorded to their account.

If I had to guess, I would say that most likely it was the community voting to have it migrated, and davidpostill acted on compiling votes. (This happens alot)

While I do not think the system here is broken, I do feel like it could use some improvement. I have brought this up with the community before, that each one of us seems to interpret these questions, and the guidelines for asking questions somewhat differently. [Do we need better definitions for off-topic questions in the help center?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13601/do-we-need-better-definitions-for-off-topic-questions-in-the-help-center)

It seems by your upvotes, that it's not only me that agrees this shouldn't have been migrated. Unfortunately, it would have been easier for the community to reopen it if it hadn't been migrated. ( Usually just Requiring 5-reopen votes from community members, which you seem to have support here for that.)

Your options are:

1. do what you have done, this is the correct arena to raise attention
   to the problem.
2. Reach out to the moderators chatroom, sometimes even our moderators
   don't agree with community actions, or each other. It's worth a
   shot.
3. Explain to a moderator at android SE you think the question was
   migrated in error, refer to this meta post.

The point I'm trying to make is that neither the community, or moderators are perfect. We volunteer our time because most of us genuinely like helping other people. Each one of us gets things wrong from time to time, and I can attest to having question review fatigue from time to time. (I usually just retire for the day when it happens)

~Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for the response. I try to keep in mind everyone can make mistakes and that's why I tried asking here calmly instead of getting mad at the moderator himself.